# How to convert GitHub Wiki into GitHub pages?

Tags: github, markdown, wiki

I want my existing GitHub Wiki to be served as GitHub pages.

I tried copying all the `.md` files into `/docs` and [setting that as the source for pages](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/) - but it breaks all the internal links.

So I see `Read the [[documentation]] or [[Help|get help]].` rather than links.

What's the easiest way to host my wiki on GitHub pages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create manual Markdown links to each page.

`[[documentation]]` and `[[Help|get help]]` style links are [wikilinks](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-links-to-wikis/#using-a-wiki-markup-syntax-to-make-links) and generally only used in wikis. They are not part of the standard Markdown syntax and not supported by [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) (which GitHub Pages uses under the hood). Note that GitHub Wiki supports [both styles](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-links-to-wikis/#using-regular-markup-syntax-to-make-links), so you could edit your links before importing if you like.

Either way, you need to edit your links to manually point to the appropriate pages using the standard markdown syntax:

```
Read the [documentation](path/to/documentation/) or [Help](path/to/get_help.html)
```

Of course, you will need to adjust the above paths to point at the correct location. As an alternative, you may be able to use Jekyll [permalinks](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/), which could provide a shortcut for you to identify specific pages without specifying a full path.

Answer (score 3):

Just received this direct from GitHub.

---

> There is no easy answer I am afraid. You will need to script or manually change the wiki format URLs to proper markdown format.
>
> We did just add relative links to GitHub Pages though:
>
> https://github.com/blog/2290-relative-links-for-github-pages
>
> Which should make things easier at least, as you won't need to fully qualify all the URLs.
>
> So you can change:
>
> `Read the [[documentation]] or [[Help|get help]].`
>
> to
>
> `Read the [documentation](documentation.md) or [Help](get%20help.md).`
>
> Alternatively, you may be able to use pandoc and the script below to do the conversion for you:
>
> https://github.com/philipashlock/mediawiki-to-markdown
>
> But I haven't tested it myself so I can't guarantee it will work.
>
> This could be  useful feature though, so I will share it with the team in the hope of an easy converter in the future

Answer (score 0):

There are tool to do it automatically. Have a look at [github-wikito-converter](https://github.com/yakivmospan/github-wikito-converter).

> Generate HTML & PDF documentation from Github wiki or any other markdown-based wiki.

Or [limedocs-wiki-converter](https://github.com/limedocs/limedocs-wiki-converter).